# Inserting data into ORC tables in Hive2

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am trying to insert data into an ORC table with Hive v2. But each time I am getting an error:

> ERROR : Job failed with java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> org.apache.orc.TypeDescription.createRowBatch(I)Lorg/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/exec/vector/VectorizedRowBatch;

Am I missing any dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

**Create a Table to LOAD Text data:**

```
CREATE TABLE txt_table(col1 <datatype>, col2 <datatype>) STORED AS TEXTFILE;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/../../file.txt' INTO TABLE txt_table;
```

**Load Data into ORC Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE orc_table(col1 <datatype>, col2 <datatype>) STORED AS ORC;
INSERT INTO TABLE orc_table SELECT * FROM txt_table;
```

Comment: I tried this... But it's also giving the same error. The thing is, when my engine is MapReduce, the inserts are working. But, When my engine is Spark, I am getting this error.